# Will using anonymous struct initializations put extra copies on the stack?

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

Consider this code

```
struct A { int m; };

int main()
{
    A a; // I beleive this should put space on the stack with sizeof(A) bytes
    a = A{5};
}
```

After putting `a` on the stack, does the line after create another `A` object then sets that to `a` or does it just set the values in `a`?

Comment: Answers to code generation questions like this will always be compiler-specific, and dependent on compiler options like optimization levels. The only way to know for sure is to look at the generated assembly code. But really, why would the compiler emit code that allocates a second object, just to copy its values to the first?

Comment: If you have a modern compiler it's a fair bet that it will not generate any code for that, unless you use debug options.

Comment: You don't have an anonymous struct, you have `struct A`. A *declaration* does not reserve bytes on the stack, a *definition* does. All a declaration does is tell the compiler "*this thing*" will be *defined* later.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin What kind of initialization would the a = A{5} be called?

Comment: @khalawarrior, that will by an assignment, not an initialization.

Comment: That is is *definition*, it defines `a` and assigns a value. (that triggers the reservation of memory by the compiler)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I believe that by "anonymous struct initializations" it is asking about the expression `A{5}`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, `a` is defined by the line `A a;`.

Comment: You are correct @SidS -- the compiler knows the size of `A` at that time.

Comment: C++ the language has no notion of stack (apart from std::stack).The call stack is an implementation detail. Any reasonable implementation won't use any stack at all for this.

Answer (score 2):

Given that `a` is not used at all, a compiler may reduce your posted `main` function to a function with an empty body. However, setting aside compiler optimizations, let's examine what you are asking the program to do:

```
A a;
```

That line says: Construct an object of type `A`. Use the compiler generated default constructor to construct the object. As per the standard, that leaves `a.m` uninitilized.

```
a = A{5};
```

That lines says: Construct a temporary object of type `A` using `{5}` and assign that temporary object to `a`. The syntax used for constructing the temporary object is such that the `m` of the object will be initialized to `5`. After that line, the value of `a.m` will be `5`. The temporary object will be destroyed at the end of that statement.

As for the question in the title of your post...

> Will using anonymous struct initializations put extra copies on the stack?

The language does not specify where the temporary object, what you call the anonymous `struct`, is placed. It is up to the implementation to decide where to put it.

Comment: What is the name of the expression `A{5}`? This is what i was referring to as the _anonymous struct initializer_.

Comment: @khalawarrior, expressions don't have names. It is just an expression. The expression evaluates to an object of type `A`. I don't think it's wrong to call that object an anonymous object although I am not sure whether the standard refers to it using that term. The key phrase there is *I am not sure*.

Comment: @RSahu: Of course, the "as if" rule allows compilers to skip all of that, since `A` is a trivial type.